# Can jhipster export-jdl export entire application?

Tags: jhipster

I have a jhipster app that I created with various specific options e.g. monolith, mysql etc etc, can I export this entire stack for someone else to use or is it just able to export the entity relationships ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.yo-rc.json` file in your project root. There are stored options that you mentioned, like application or DB type